# Combining two promises using promise.all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise

I have two promises from two different API calls in my VUE JS app, I was thinking maybe both could be combined using a `promise.all()` approach? If so how could I do this?

API.js

```js
async function getForecast(lat, lon) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${WEATHER_API_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function getAddress(lat, lon) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${ADDRESS_API_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

App.vue

```js
loadWeather(lat, lon) {
  API.getAddress(lat, lon).then(result => {
    this.address = result.name;
  });
  API.getForecast(lat, lon).then(result => {
    this.forecast = result;
  });
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by 'combined'. What are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: I have two promises in my `loadWeather` method, I was wondering if a `promise.all` would be of use here?

Comment: @Rob What is the supposed advantage of combining them? What do you want to achieve that your current code doesn't do?

Comment: Better code standards? If the code is acceptable like this then I'll roll with it. I'm not too familiar with combining promises as I'm learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to existing answers, this is when `async..await` becomes useful, since it's already used in other functions. The array that `Promise.all` resolves to can be destructured:

```
async loadWeather(lat, lon) {
  const [address, forecast] = await Promise.all([
    API.getAddress(lat, lon),
    API.getForecast(lat, lon)
  ]);
  this.address = address.name;
  this.forecast = forecast;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Promise.all to combine your calls. See below how you might do that...

(I'm using setTimouts in place of your fetch requests)

```
const functionA = async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(); }, 2000);
  });

  return "A";
};

const functionB = async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(); }, 3000);
  });

  return "B";
};

const getResults = async () => {
  const result = await Promise.all([functionA(), functionB()]);
  return result;
};

getResults().then(result => console.log(result));
```

View on https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-lake-qupp7?file=/src/index.js

To translate this to your example, we can therefore do...

```
// promise
function loadWeather(lat, lon) {
  Promise.all([
    API.getAddress(lat, lon),
    API.getForecast(lat, lon)
  ]).then(([address, forecast]) => {
    this.address = address.name;
    this.forecast = forecast;
  });
}

// or async/await
async function loadWeather(lat, lon) {
  const [address, forecast] = await Promise.all([
    API.getAddress(lat, lon),
    API.getForecast(lat, lon)
  ]);

  this.address = address.name;
  this.forecast = forecast;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, decide if you want the promise to fail if any of the two API calls fail. `Promise.all` will fail in this case, `Promise.allSettled` will not. It depends on what you want for your app.

To combine, you can do the following:

```
loadWeather(lat, lon) {
  Promise.all([
    API.getAddress(lat, lon),
    API.getForecast(lat, lon)
  ]).then(([addressResult, forecastResult]) => {
    this.address = addressResult.name;
    this.forecast = forecastResult;
  });
}
```

`Promise.all` returns an array of results. This makes sense if you consider that you pass it an array of promises.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write

```
loadWeather(lat, lon) {
  Promise.all([
    API.getAddress(lat, lon),
    API.getForecast(lat, lon),
  ]).then(([addressResult, forecastResult]) => {
    this.address = addressResult.name;
    this.forecast = forecastResult;
  });
}
```

However, it doesn't really seem necessary, as both functions handle errors already and there doesn't seem to be a reason why the property assignments would need to wait for *both* promises to fulfill.